# Add multiple classes data in single class using SOLID design pattern

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have `Product`, `Item1` and `Item2` classes.The goal is to consolidate all of the Items in product class into a single list so that they can be sorted and
displayed on the client's website.I want this in C# using SOLID principle

```
public class Product
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
and here are list of datas are in this class
-- var list1 = new List<Item1>();
public class Item1
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
-- var list2 = new List<Item2>();
public class Item2
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you explain exactly what is the problem? You mentioned a base class, what do you mean?

Comment: thanks for your response, I have modified the question

Comment: The question is still not clear. What is the expected result? a `List<Product>`?

Comment: I think i get it, he has 2 lists of diferent types, and he wants to join them on another list (List<Products>) with wich type (Item1 and Item2). Is that it?

Comment: hey guys thanks for your quick response and sorry, I cannot describe exact output, I want like this........  
var list1 = new List<Item1>(); 
and var list2 = new List<Item2>(); 
and I want to these two list in product class like this var p1 = list1.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id}),p1 = list2.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id});
and merge to in a single list var finalProduct = p1.Concat(p2).Tolist(); after that I can call finalProduct anywhere in the project but I want this using SOLID design. whatever extra clasess take, doesn't matter but return type should be product class list.
thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags. Make sure, however, not to invalidate existing answers by your edit!

Comment: What's the difference between the Item1 and Item2 classes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to override the values of product as well as have a list of children Items, I would suggest that you declare values you intend to override as virtual, and make another class available that can also take a list of items as required, while inheriting from the parent product table.

```
    public class Product
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductFull : Product
    {
        public override Guid Id { get; set; }
        public override string Name { get; set; }
        public override string Type { get; set; }

        public List<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }

        public List<Item2> Item2s { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item1
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item2
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

From MSDN:

Virtual properties behave like abstract methods, except for the differences in declaration and invocation syntax.
It is an error to use the virtual modifier on a static property.
A virtual inherited property can be overridden in a derived class by including a property declaration that uses the override modifier.

Comment: Oh Right, if your items aren't intended to be collections, simply remove the `List<..>` and replace it with `Item1` and `Item2`. Use the `ProductFull` as your model instead.

Comment: hey guys thanks for your quick response and sorry, I cannot describe exact output, I want like this........  
var list1 = new List<Item1>(); 
and var list2 = new List<Item2>(); 
and I want to these two list in product class like this var p1 = list1.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id}),p1 = list2.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id});
and merge to in a single list var finalProduct = p1.Concat(p2).Tolist(); after that I can call finalProduct anywhere in the project but I want this using SOLID design. whatever extra clasess take, doesn't matter but return type should be product class list.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel to handle your display concerns. This respects the single responsibility principle. The responsibilities of the ViewModel are displaying data and validating `<form>` inputs filled in by the user (if any). The data to be displayed can be aggregated from many sources.

Use a mapping between your persisted entities/ domain entities/ data transfer objects and your ViewModel. Define a mapping from each source class to your ViewModel. Using a library such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for this is highly recommended.

For Example:

```
public class ProductDetailsViewModel {
    // Display attribute as an example of a view concern
    [Display(Name = "ProductDetails_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class ProductListViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<ProductDetailsViewModel> ProductDetails {get; set;}
}


// Example of mapping by hand:
var item1 = new Item1();
var item2 = new Item2();
var vm1 = new ProductDetailsViewModel { Name = item1.Name };
var vm2 = new ProductDetailsViewModel { Name = item2.Name };
var productList = new ProductListViewModel {ProductDetails = new [] {vm1, vm2}};
```

Comment: hey guys thanks for your quick response and sorry, I cannot describe exact output, I want like this........  
var list1 = new List<Item1>(); 
and var list2 = new List<Item2>(); 
and I want to these two list in product class like this var p1 = list1.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id}),p1 = list2.Select(s=> new Product{Id=s.Id});
and merge to in a single list var finalProduct = p1.Concat(p2).Tolist(); after that I can call finalProduct anywhere in the project but I want this using SOLID design. whatever extra clasess take, doesn't matter but return type should be product class list.
thanks

Comment: You could define an interface on Product, Item1, Item2 that contains the properties that are common with Product, e.g. `interface IProductLike { Guid Id { get; set; } string Name { get; set; }}` and then map Item1 and Item2 to Product like you outlined above. The interface helps with consistency. But there is the danger that you will start mixing concerns in the Product class, e.g. if you have to attribute the properties differently for your OR Mapper, for WCF and to display them. Therefore a common design principle is to separate frontend and backend into different classes.